# Mongoid how to turn nested attribute into object?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have MongoDB  collection in schema like

```
deal
    - id
    - locations
        [ 
            {city: A, zip: 111}
            {city: B, zip: 222}
            {city: C, zip: 333}
        ]
```

I used Mongoid to interact with MongoDB.

```
  class Deal
     include Mongoid::Document
     store_in collection: :deals
      ...
  end
```

With Deal.find('xxx') I can obtain an object d. I can use format like d.id and d.locations. However, d.locations[0] is a Hash object. I can only use format d.locations[0][:city] rather than the preferred d.locations[0].city.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new mongoid object that will be embeded in your object

```
  class Deal
     include Mongoid::Document
     embeds_many :locations
      ...
  end

  class Location
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :deal
    field :city, :zip
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That should work, but I just have too many such fields and I don't want to have each of them this way. ActiveRecord can automatically convert all the nested attributes so I assume there's such way in MongoID.